# How to use x-template to separate out template from Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, xtemplate

Tried to separate out template from Vue Component as below but it does not work.
Referencing only vue.js file and not browsify.

```
Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
    template: '#checkbox-template',
    data() {
        return { checked: false, title: 'Check me' }
    },
    methods: {
        check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
    }
});

<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-template">
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
        <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Or any alternate way to separate out template from vue component.

Comment: Your `<script>` tag needs to be in an HTML file. It's difficult to tell from your question if that is or is not the case

Comment: I have tried by including into separate component file and also, component and script tag both in html file. But did't work.

Comment: @user3711357 Refer to this link: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/646897363

I collected the ways to separate template from Vue component.

Answer (score 8):

You define [X-Templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates) in your HTML file. See below for a brief demo

```js
// this is the JS file, eg app.js
Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
    template: '#checkbox-template',
    data() {
        return { checked: false, title: 'Check me' }
    },
    methods: {
        check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
    }
});

new Vue({el:'#app'})
```

```css
/* CSS file */
.checkbox-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}
.checkbox {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.checkbox.checked {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML file -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-template">
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
        <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
        <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
    </div>
</script>
<div id="app"> <!-- the root Vue element -->
  <my-checkbox></my-checkbox> <!-- your component -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my bad english it's not my main language!

Try it!

You need generate two file in same directory:

- path/to/checkboxComponent.vue
- path/to/checkboxComponent.html

### In checkboxComponent.vue file

```
<script>
// Add imports here eg:
// import Something from 'something';
export default {
    template: require('./checkboxComponent.html'),
    data() {
        return { checked: false, title: 'Check me' }
    },
    methods: {
        check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
    }
}
</script>
```

### In checkboxComponent.html file

```
<template>
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
        <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now you need to declare this Component in same file you declare Vue app, as the following:

```
Vue.component('my-checkbox', require('path/to/checkboxComponent.vue').default);
```

### In my case

I have three files with these directories structure:

```
js/app.js
js/components/checkboxComponent.vue
js/components/checkboxComponent.html
```

In app.js, i'm declare the Vue app, so the require method path need to start with a dot, like this:

```
Vue.component('my-checkbox', require('./components/checkboxComponent.vue').default);
```

Comment: To be able tu use signle file components  you will need to install vue CLI and webpack. https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#npm

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code snippet you posted is not the whole thing. Here is what I've tested.

in file x_template.js

```
export default {
  template: '#x-template',
  data() {
    return { point: 1 }
  },
  methods: {
    inc() { this.point++ }
  }
}
```

in x_template_app.js file

```
import * as Vue from "vue"
import XTemplate from "./x_template"

const app = Vue.createApp(XTemplate)
app.mount("#x-template-app")
```

Then in the html file

```
<div id="x-template-app">  
</div>  

<script type="text/x-template" id="x-template">
  <p>Point is: {{ point }}. <button @click="inc">Inc</button></p>
</script>
```

As we can see the template actually defined in html file with a script tab wrapped.