# Why does re-initialising a Vue app doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue not as a SPA, but only as a widget on a page. There is a popup plugin (a jQuery plugin thats working outside of Vue) that deletes the Vue app's HTML and put it back again for the purpose of repositioning it. I want to run my code that would re-initiate the Vue after repositioning is done. I don't have access to the popup plugin and cannot change the way it works.

I have tried this code to reinitialize the Vue App:

```
function initializeApp() {
  app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
    // other options. 
  }); 
}

// This function would run after popup has removed and added the HTML of vue app back.
function afterPopupOpen() {
  app.$destroy()
  initializeApp()
}
```

But it doesn't work. After re-initiating the Vue app click handlers don't seem to work.

I have created a code sandbox to demonstrate the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-app-reinitialize-example-qcovs4?file=/index.html

Notice that the counter button stops working after the Re-initialise button is clicked.

Comment: The template that you use `<button @click="add">count is {{count}}</button>` is lost after the first init. Stick to component-based approach for reusable stuff. If you need to keep a template in HTML page, you can use external template https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295908/how-to-use-x-template-to-separate-out-template-from-vue-component . You didn't clarify what is popup plugin and how it works, so it's not known for sure what are your options here

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, Thanks for your comment. I have added some explanation for the popup, it's jQuery plugin that is independent of Vue. The external template sounds good, I will give it a try.

I was hoping there was a way to reinitialize the event listeners in some way :(